# Python litestar AttributeError on GET / 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'to_asgi_response'

Tags: python, litestar

I am getting this error soon after running the app.

poetry run litestar --app 'litestar_app.app:app' run --reload --debug

it starts normal but when i open http://127.0.0.1:8000 it shows below error

```
AttributeError on GET /
'coroutine' object has no attribute 'to_asgi_response'
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\handlers\http_handlers\_utils.py in handler at line 152
    async def handler(
        data: Response,
        app: Litestar,
        request: Request,
        **kwargs: Any,  # kwargs is for return dto
    ) -> ASGIApp:
        response = await after_request(data) if after_request else data  # type:ignore[arg-type,misc]
        return response.to_asgi_response(  # type: ignore
            app=None,
            background=background,
            cookies=cookie_list,
            headers=normalized_headers,
            media_type=media_type,
            request=request,
            status_code=status_code,
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\handlers\http_handlers\base.py in get.to_response at line 528
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\routes\http.py in HTTPRoute._call_handler_function at line 158
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\routes\http.py in HTTPRoute._get_response_for_request at line 134
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\routes\http.py in HTTPRoute.handle at line 82
â–¼ C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\pythonex-app-U7JqGUH_-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\litestar\middleware\exceptions\middleware.py in ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.__call__ at line 192
```

app.py

```py
from litestar import Litestar
from .config.compression import compression_config
from .config.template import template_config
from .config.static_files import static_files_config
from .controllers.index import IndexController
from .controllers.api.users import UsersController
from litestar.config.cors import CORSConfig
from pythonex_app.config.app import app_config

# If running locally, allow all origins. Otherwise, don't allow any.
# This is to prevent CORS errors when running locally
cors_config = CORSConfig() if app_config.ENV == "LOCAL" else None

app = Litestar(
    route_handlers=[IndexController, UsersController],
    middleware=[],
    compression_config=compression_config,
    template_config=template_config,
    static_files_config=static_files_config,
    cors_config=cors_config,
)
```

Comment: can you show some code? there is some code in the error, but can you show your app code?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Added app.py in the question

Please let me know if you are looking for any specific file

Comment: class IndexController(Controller):
    path = "/"

    @get(["/", "/{path: path}"], include_in_schema=True, sync_to_thread=True)
    async def render_index(self) -> Template:
        return Template(template_name="index.html")


adding async  before def render_index(self) solved the issue.

Thanks